# Edited shadow and passwd to clear root password but new password doesn't work

Tags: linux, passwords, embedded, microcontroller

I'm working on a product that is running Linux version 3.4.8 on an atmel micrcontroller.

I decided to connect to the device using the debug port but discovered it was password protected and nobody in the company knew the password.

I changed the shadow and passwd file via GPRS, (GPRS was fine), and rebooted.  I can now access the device but if I try to set the password using paswd, when I reboot it doesn't accept my password, then I have to clear the shadow and passwd files again.

Any ideas why the passwd command does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that "/etc" is mounted on a ramdisk (or as tmpfs), which allows you to change the password at runtime but the changes are not propagated to the actual passwd and shadow files. The "/etc" is remounted on bootup from a flash device causing the old settings to be used. 
After logging in to the system execute mount and check where "/" or "/etc" is mounted, then check the type. A value of tmpfs will prove the statements above. Also check if "/etc" is a link to a folder in "/var". "/var" is usually on tmpfs.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback.  To be honest I gave up! However, I'm looking at it again now /etc does not appear to be mounted...# df -P
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/xxxx                XX.0M     XX.3M     XX.7M  XX% /
devtmpfs                 XX.7M         0     XX.7M   X% /xxxx
tmpfs                    XX.7M    XXX.0K     XX.6M   X% /xxx
/dev/xxxxxxxx2          XX.0M     XX.7M    XX0.3M  XX% /xxxx

Comment: I xx'ed out the parameters as it is a proprietary system but suffice to say none correspond to /etc

Comment: It might not be explicitly mounted. Where is your "/" root mounted? If it is in a "tmpfs" then it follows that "/etc" is also there.

Comment: tmpfs is mounted on /tmp only.  /dev/root is mounted on /